# Получить символ по его utf-8 коду

Tags: php, utf-8

В функцию приходит массив из кодов символов (так уж сложилось что из за особенностей некоторых браузеров в одном из методов текст приходится отправлять так).
Как получить из кода символа сам символ, чтобы пробежаться по массиву и собрать из него строку, что то типа

```
foreach ($orderText as $hexSimbol) {
    $resText.=chr($hexSimbol);
}
```

только chr() заменить на другую функцию (может самописную), чтобы она возвращала кирилические символы?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Функция **uchr** получив на вход число вернет строку из одного символа, получив на вход массив чисел вернет строку, составленную из этих чисел.

```
function uchr ($codes) {
    if (is_scalar($codes)) $codes= func_get_args();
    $str= '';
    foreach ($codes as $code) $str.= html_entity_decode('&#'.$code.';',ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8');
    return $str;
}
```

Что поучительно, пример кода взят отсюда: [PHP:chr](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.chr.php#74784).

А вообще, для любого языка такую функцию можно найти введя в Google запрос:

```
имя_языка unicode chr
```

Comment: Спасибо, до этого примера недогуглил